# MongoDB установка. прописал следующее на фото, оно в режиме ожидания почему?

Tags: mongodb

[image: установка]

чего ждем? почему в режиме ожидания

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы запустили mongod.exe, то есть сам сервер MongoDB, и он находится в ожидании подключения какого-либо клиента, это его нормальное состояние. Чтобы подключиться клиентом к серверу - запустите mongo.exe.